# How to set the raw body in jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Instead of sending a list of key/value pairs, I need to send a JSON string as the body of the POST request.
I make this POST request using jQuery's $.ajax function.
How do I set it correctly?

When I say JSON string, I mean something like: `{action:'x',params:['a','b','c']}` .

This is how I would use this JSON string in PHP on the server:

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
```

Results in:

```
stdClass Object
    action = x
    params = Array
        (
    0 = a
    1 = b
    2 = c
        )
```

Comment: I understand now - you want to somehow actually replace the body of the xhr request with a json string of your choosing?  No idea here - hopefully an expert will come by and say whether this is even possible

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Try:

```
$.ajax('url',{
    'data': JSON.stringify(yourJSONObject), //{action:'x',params:['a','b','c']}
    'type': 'POST',
    'processData': false,
    'contentType': 'application/json' //typically 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', but the service you are calling may expect 'text/json'... check with the service to see what they expect as content-type in the HTTP header.
});
```

Comment: 'contentType': 'application/json' in my opinion.

Comment: Your syntax is odd -- see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ -- but the processData does indeed do the job.

Comment: My syntactic is also 7 years old. :)

Answer (score 6):

if you dont specify the key  i think it will post as the body without the key like

```
$.ajax({
data:JSON.stringify({action:'x',params:['a','b','c']})
});
```