# building, sending, and deserializing a json object that contains arrays

Tags: javascript, ajax, serialization

I'm reaaallly new at JSON, but here's what I got. I needed to create an object that contains an array/list and a couple flat fields. For example:

```
var names= new Array();
    names[0] = "Christy";
    names[1] = "Jeremy";
var obj = { 
   names: names, 
   age: "21+",
   comment: "friends"
};
```

I then stringify it and attempt to send it to a pagemethod via AJAX:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
sendData(obj);
```

And then the send:

```
function sendData(jsonData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/TestArray",
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('win');
        },
        error: function (a, b, ex) {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
}
```

so all together:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var names = new Array();
        names[0] = "Christy";
        names[1] = "Jeremy";
        var obj = {
            names: names, 
            age: "21+",
            comment: "friends"
        };
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
        sendData(jsonData);
    });

    function sendData(jsonData) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/TestArray",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (a, b, ex) {
                alert("oops: " + ex);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. It doesn't even get to the webmethod, rather it goes straight to the error function. But just for the sake of conversation, this is what I have in the codebehind:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string TestArray(string guids)
{
    Comment cmt = (Comment)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(guids, typeof(Comment));
    return "Winner";
}
```

And of course class im trying to deserialize into:

```
public class Comment
{
    public List<string> names { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084625/283366) for information on sending JSON data in the raw post body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the signature of your web method:

```
public static string TestArray(string guids)
```

you must send a single string argument whereas you are sending an entire complex JSON object which doesn't match. So:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ guids: 'foo bar' });
```

Now if you wanted to send a complex structure use:

```
public static string TestArray(Comment comment)
```

and then:

```
var names = new Array();
    names[0] = "Christy";
    names[1] = "Jeremy";
var obj = { 
   names: names, 
   age: "21+",
   comment: "friends"
};
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ comment: obj });
```

Also inside your web method don't do any JSON serialization/deserializations. That's infrastructure stuff that's handled for you by the framework. So to recap:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string TestArray(Comment comment)
{
    return "Winner";
}
```

and then:

```
var names = new Array();
    names[0] = "Christy";
    names[1] = "Jeremy";
var obj = { 
   names: names, 
   age: "21+",
   comment: "friends"
};
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ comment: obj });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/TestArray",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        // Notice the .d property. That's ASP.NET PageMethods
        // serialize the response.
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (a, b, ex) {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

Also in order to be able to easily debug such problems in the future I would very strongly recommend you using a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug which shows you any potential js errors that you might have as well as all network traffic including AJAX requests.

Answer (score -1):

You're json data object does not have to be Stringified. JQuery automatically creates a json object for it:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
sendData(jsonData);
```

Can become:

```
sendData(obj);
```

Also, in code behind you use JsonConvert from the JSON.Net library, .NET also has a (somewhat limited) JSON parser called JavaScriptSerializer. That way you can use something like:

```
public static string TestArray(string guids)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    // Deserialize
    Comment cmt = serializer.Deserialize<Comment>(guids);
}
```

Comment: If you do that, jQuery will post a set of key/value pairs

Comment: still did not work. "Internal Server Error". If I remove the age and comment fields from the json object and treat it as a list in the webmethod, it works find. But i need the array.