# PHP $_FILES and Jquery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, file, post

I want to do a form which allows to upload a file through a JQuery submit. I have this html code:

```
<form method="post" id="addPhotoForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="text" name="words" />
    <input type="button" onclick="go();" />
</form>
```

`go();` allows to submit (JS / JQuery) :

```
function go() {
    $.post('processing.php', $("#addPhotoForm").serialize()).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
}
```

and PHP code:

```
var_dump($_POST['words']);
var_dump($_FILES);
die('');
```

Here, `$_POST['words']` displays the right thing but `$_FILES` stays an empty array even after selecting a file. Where is the problem please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$("#addPhotoForm").serialize()` ignores file fields.

Comment: file inputs can't be serialized, you have to use the formData object.

Comment: Ok what have I to write so?

Comment: You might want to take a look at how to manually send data in the POST body: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084296/how-to-set-the-raw-body-in-jquery-ajax#answer-9084625

Comment: a good solution here : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples we just have to use the html form normaly, it worked first try. Then use $_FILES as usual