# how to send json data and 1-n files in POST body use javascript

Tags: javascript, http, post, request

I have from like this:

```
<form id="form" method='post' action="http://192.168.1.33/api/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>User login: </label>
<input type="text" id="userLogin"><br />
<label>User password</label>
<input type="text" id="userPass"><br /><br />
    <label>Input command here</label>
    <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="users" id="command" name="command"><br/><br />
    <input type="file" name="file1"><br/>
    <input type="file" name="file2"><br/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<h3>Output: </h3>

<div id="output"></div>
```

And simple javascript code. This code gets form data (attached files) and creating 2 fields in http header with userName and userPass, and send it to my api:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var myCommand = document.querySelector('#command');
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function (event) {
        if (window.FormData) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var data = new FormData(form);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = form.getAttribute('action') + '?' + myCommand.value;

            xhr.open('post', url);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-auth-user', document.querySelector('#userLogin').value);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-auth-pass', document.querySelector('#userPass').value);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    // server response: xhr.responseText
                    document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhr.send(data);
        }
    };

    (function() {
        document.querySelector('#userLogin').value = "user1";
        document.querySelector('#userPass').value = "user";

    })();
</script>
```

How can I add json data in body request use javascript? Json like this:

```
{
"id":"",
"status":0,

"documentName":"user",
"documentDesctiption":"",
"documentAttachedUsers":"id, id, id"
}
```

In fact I don't need form. I need to send 1-n files and one json string in POST body.

Now Api (php) receives just only form data (files). I plan on getting the body like this:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the raw body in jQuery Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084296/how-to-set-the-raw-body-in-jquery-ajax)

Comment: No, it's not same answer. 1. I don't need jquery. 2. I need send form data + json in body.

Comment: Since you are already sending form data with your request (which will result in a certain Content-Type of the request already), you can not add JSON “as JSON” at the same time. Probably easiest if you stringify your JSON, and send that string as the value of an additional parameter, that you can then decode on the server side again.

Comment: In fact I need just sent 1-n files and json for this files. No more. I created form just for simple attached files

Comment: Well then do that as described. `FormData` has an `append` method.